# Nginx: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, linux, nginx, server

I upload a video file (Duration: 25', Size: 243.3MB)

I edited in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` like that:

```
client_max_body_size 480000M;
```

And, I also edited in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` like that:

```
max_input_time = 480000
max_execution_time = 480000
upload_max_filesize = 240000M
post_max_size = 480000M
memory_limit = 240000M
```

But I always get the error: **413 Request Entity Too Large**

Please help me. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

As a fact 413 error could be caysed be small value of client_max_body_size. Could I sure that you restart|reload your nginx?

Comment: Yes, I did it.
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
And this is my nginx.conf

http {
server {
                client_max_body_size 480000M;
        }
}

Comment: Don't you have any proxy server in front of?

Comment: No, I just create a input file and upload the video.

Answer (score 0):

### Apache alternative solution to the error 413

For those who have had this problem in apache, i had the same issue and i solved it. First i tried changing all the same variables you tried (`max_input_time`, `max_execution_time`, `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`) and nothing worked at first.

The way i make it works was by changing the `LimitRequestBody` directive on the file `httpd-php.conf`.

> Note: If you are having problems finding where is the directive, you must find in your `httpd.conf` or `apache.conf` where the `<IfModule php_module>` directive configuration is.

The default value was 9524288 (9.08MB).

```
LimitRequestBody 9524288
```

So i had to set it to 50MB (converted to bytes 52428800).

```
LimitRequestBody 52428800
```

Then i restarted the apache service and all started working well.

I hope this answer could help any other developer who is having this issue and ended on this answer.

You can read the official documentation here: [LimitRequestBody Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)